# How do I unload code from a Lua context

Tags: c++, memory-management, lua

The context here is Lua embedded in a C++ app.

I have used the function `luaL_loadbuffer()` for a long time and it works fine.

However, now I have the need to unload. Why would I want to do that?

I have internal C++ maps that I want to initialize with Lua scripts, but then throw each Lua script away once the C++ map has been initialized. The Lua table uses a lot more memory (7 megs vs. 200k for C++) and cannot do functions like `lower_bound()` and `upper_bound()` which I need.

The map elements are `std::pair<uint32_t, uint32_t>`, essentially ip addresses stored in binary.

Any way to unload Lua code that's been loaded into a Lua context after it executes once?

Comment: I'd have thought that dropping all references to your loaded lua and letting the garbage collector do its job would work nicely. Tearing down the lua state and recreating it would also work, though it would be a bit of a nuclear option.

Answer (score 0):

If by *unload* you mean undo the effects of running some Lua code, then it cannot be done unless you save the state of what is precious before running the code. This can be done by sandboxing the code.

If you just want to remove a Lua table, set to nil all references to it and let the table be garbage collected automatically or manually.